# Can I insert an item with a specific color in a Listbox?

Tags: excel, listview, listboxitem, vba

I'm developing an application with VBA in Excel 2013. I have a ListBox with items and I want to give each item a specific color depending on a criteria, I searched on the net but it says that it is impossible to do so, is that true?

I tried to use the listview (Microsoft ListView Control) but it doesn't show on the extra controls in the userform.

Does anyone know how to do give each item a specific color depending on a criterion using a Listbox if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot change the colour of individual items in an Excel listbox.**

---

There are alternative ways you can achieve a similar result:

- Use the [ActiveX ListView control](https://10tec.com/articles/excel-vba-listview-control-examples.aspx) like examples [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/37208985-728e-4f28-96fb-4c2177f024a1/how-to-change-properties-of-an-individual-row-in-a-listbox-control?forum=excel) or [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?9152-Change-the-color-of-text-in-a-listbox-based-upon-a-certain-criteria) or [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?33803-Solved-Changing-color-of-item-in-listbox-based-on-value-of-specific-cell).
- You can dynamically create an HTML Table and display that in a web browser control.
- You can manipulate Excel cells to *look* and *act* like a listbox.

Your best best *might* be the ListView control but it could take some fancy footwork.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Using the ListView Control (Visual Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733652(v=vs.60).aspx)
- MSDN : [Using ActiveX Controls on Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/using-activex-controls-on-sheets)
- MSDN : [ListView Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276570(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Good to hear!  I've never actually used one, but I'm less of a formatter, more of a data geek :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize a ListBox in a UserForm, then you may use this DesignListBox

https://github.com/balin77/ExcelDesignListBox

It allows you to change any color, FontSize or Style.