# Make row red in Excel Userform ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a Userform that populates a ListBox with data from a table. What I would like it to do is if there is any missing data, make that row red.

[image]

This is the code for the Userform but I don't know where to start for the row colours.

```
Dim iRow As Long

DeclareVars

iRow = Backtable.ListRows.Count + 1 ' idetifying the last row. + 1 added due to the form not shopwing the last line in table

With frmform

    .txtID.value = ""
    .txtArea.value = ""
    .txtSupplier.value = ""
    .txtItemDetails.value = ""
    .txtContactDetails.value = ""
    .txtConRenewalDate.value = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .txtFreq.value = "e.g. 4 for 4 times per year"
    .txtNextService.value = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .txtRisk.value = "'Y' or 'N'"
    
    '--------------------------------
    
    'Default Color
    .txtID.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtArea.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtSupplier.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtItemDetails.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtContactDetails.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtConRenewalDate.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtFreq.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtNextService.BackColor = vbWhite
    .txtRisk.BackColor = vbWhite
    
    '-----------------------------------------------
    
    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = Backtable.ListColumns.Count
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30,60,75,55,60,45,30,70,70"
    
    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:I" & iRow
    Else
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:I2"
    End If
    
    '-----------------------------------------------
    
End With
```

Comment: You cannot change the color of individual item in a ListBox. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49219617/11071704).

Comment: @romulax14 Ah damn, ok, thanks

Comment: A workaround would be to set the list multiselect property to multi or extended, then create a filter to identify the lines you need to be highlighted and apply it (at request). You can correct the problems (if this is the purpose of highlighting) and test the results again... Thinking deeper, you can even create a second listbox (where the filter to be implemented), put it bellow the real one, which will have some transparency. The tricky part will be to synchronize the scroll, but it would not be something extremely difficult, I think...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I insert an item with a specific color in a Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219166/can-i-insert-an-item-with-a-specific-color-in-a-listbox)

Comment: See [An MSForms (all VBA) treeview for Access, Excel And Word](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp) offering a free editable treeview solution (including 64bit) including formatting and other features (in addition to paid pro-versions).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the color of individual item in a ListBox.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219166/can-i-insert-an-item-with-a-specific-color-in-a-listbox/49219617#49219617).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using a ListView control; unfortunately this requires a lot more work on the part of the programmer.